# How to configure MediaConvert to trigger different events for different inputs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-media-convert

I have configured MediaConvert to trigger a success event which is listened/handled by a lambda.

But I have different kinds of jobs for MediaConvert, which means, on success, based on the input, I would like to trigger different sns topics or lambdas.

Is it possible to trigger different success events(sns topics) based on the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a MediaConvert job you can define a "userMetadata" object. This object could contain a key-value pair like `"type": "SOME_INDETIFIER"`. Now you can set different EventBridge rules which act based on the "type".

Comment: I was just thinking on trying out with tags. Do you see a meaningful difference between the two? Or if maybe tags don't work at all in this usecase, could you please show how would the metadata event-bridge-rule event-pattern look like? Thanks : )

Comment: I do not know if tags would work in this case. Here is an example event: https://codeshare.io/alPBdR